# Vertical alignment of content in TextBox (UWP)

Tags: xaml, uwp

does anyone know how to set text of textbox in vertical center of the box? I'm trying to make my universal app responsive, and textbox size adapts as it should, but I would need text in to be always in vertical center.

Thanks for all your time and help in advance!

My code:

```
<TextBox
    x:Name="textBox"
    Margin="10"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    Text=""
    Grid.Column="1"
    PlaceholderText="Website"
    TextAlignment="DetectFromContent"
    FontSize="20"
    FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    d:LayoutOverrides="TopPosition, BottomPosition" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a little more to it than that. Inside the template for `TextBox` are several elements. Including presenters for the placeholder text and a delete button etc.

You could add an attached property to target the embedded `ScrollViewer` and achieve most of what you want like this;

`<TextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ..../>`

Except if you're using placeholder "watermark" text and stuff, you may have to make a copy of the [template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx) and vertical position everything in there.

Hope this helps, cheers.